# How to design layout for all real devices in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating app for all screen size real Android devices. I'm designing the layout for all large and xlarge screen size devices. I created layout folder of small, normal, large, xlarge, xxlarge. I'm trying but does not properly designed.

Here is my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/ImageSwitcher01"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="253dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/back_img"
            android:paddingBottom="90dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ImageSwitcher>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonFan"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/brought_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonFan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonCustomer"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fan_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonCustomer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/customer_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you shoudl avoid using fixed dimensions or at least use different dimensions values for each __dimens.xml__ file

Comment: But how can do. Can give me a some suggestion ?

Comment: you may create different `values-<screen_target>/dimens` and declare different sizes for each target and then use `android:layout_width="@dimen/the_size_you_defined` and the sizes should be selected based on the device's screen

Comment: just replace `android:layout_height="30dp"` with `android:layout_height="@dimen/size_of_this_particular_dimen"` and create an res/values/dimen.xml file with necessary value.
also, if you use modern IDE, there is a tool for that. in Android Studio, you can press alt+enter on "30dp" value in XML file and it will suggest "Extract dimension resource..." action

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of android you set your minimum SDK to in your Android Manifest you have two options.

1 - If you want to target devices below 3.2 you should use the layout files found in your /res folder in your project. This contains various "buckets" such as layout, layout-large and layout-xlarge where you can declare how your interface looks for different sized devices. Admittedly this isn't the best to do it because as you are finding the operating system will decide what "bucket" to use to display your interface.

2 - If you are targeting devices that use 3.2 and above then you can use Smallest-width qualifiers which allow to define layouts for devices that have screen that meet the minimum widths in density pixels. This gives you a greater degree of control over which layout shown for what size screen You define the width in your layout folder name.

A quick example of how your layout folders should be named can be shown below:

Pre 3.2:

- res/layout
- res/layout-large
- res/layout-xlarge

3.2 and Above

- res/layout-sw600dp
- res/layout-sw800dp
- res/layout-sw1000dp

More information that elaborates more can be found on the Android Developer Website:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Hope this helps.